# Difference when building with MSBuild.exe on different machines

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Hello here we use ci on one of the machines (agent of Team City) the dll netstandard.dll goes to the bin on others not, we use MSBuild.exe from Visual Studio 2017 Professional. As we use WiX to generate msi we have an analyzer to see if there are any missing or missing files. This also happened with the file System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll that was not being generated in the bin on this machine but in the other yes.

Machine A and B: Windows edition: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Machine A (with problems): VS version 15.8.6 (I upgraded to the latest version thinking this was it)
Machine B: VS version 15.5.4

Machine A (with problems): .NET Framework version 461310
Machine B: .NET Framework version 460805

Comment: Run MSBuild with detailed/diagnostics logging, and then compare the log files from different machines.

Comment: In addition your question is not clearly asked and likely belongs to server-fault-board. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). **Please edit your post accordingly**, that way you can get answers